# Why isn't the best overload picked up in this case?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, overloading

I'm trying to understand why the output of the following code is different that I expect.

```
public static void Main(string[] _) 
{
    var a = new A();
    var b = new B();
    
    var ok = new System.Collections.Generic.List<object>()
    {a,b}.Select(x => Who(x));
    
    Console.WriteLine(ok.Count());
}

public static Type Who(object o)
{
    Console.WriteLine("I'm an OBJECT");
    var type = o.GetType();
    Console.WriteLine(type);
    return type;
}

public static Type Who(A a)
{
    a.Describe();
    return a.GetType();
}

public static Type Who(B b)
{
    b.Describe();
    return b.GetType();
}

public class A
{
    public virtual void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm A");
    }
}
    
public class B : A
{
    public override void Describe()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm B");
    }
}

//OUTPUT
// I'm an OBJECT
// C+A
// I'm an OBJECT
// C+B
```

link to gist [sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#gist:8779b730d3af42c8eb2ce92912d5e67a)

From the Example above, the best overload is not picked up, I don't understand why and how can I overcome this.

By removing:

```
static Type Who(object o);
```

I have to do a casting which I can't do of course.

In the real code I can't know the exact type of the collection and I want to use overload to perform different type of operation depending on the type;

Comment: If you want to defer overload resolution to runtime instead of compile time, you need to use `dynamic`. At compile time, the only type the compiler has to work from is `object` so of course that's the overload that's selected.

Comment: Why are you overloading here anyway? Passing a `B` instance to `Who(A)` will behave identically as passing it to `Who(B)`.

Comment: In the sample the `B` is derived from `A`. If in the real code you also have inheritance from the common root, then you can just specify such a root as a type for the collection and all will work as expected.

Comment: Creating a generic list in this case that simply holds `object` kinda defeats the purpose.  Consider using `var ok = new List<A>() // ....`.  Casting to `object` and writing methods like `Who(object o)` is like turning a 3D colour photo into B&W